# alert() not working for validation

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I have tried adding and removing contact fields and got it down to two for troubleshooting. I have tried it in multiple browsers but I can't seem to get an alert. Just looking to be pointed int he right direction here, another set of eyes may help!

here is the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Sugar Shippers International Snacks</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styletest.css" />
        <script src="/validateInputtesting.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
    <h2>
        Contact us!
    </h2>

    <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidateInput()">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Lets Go"
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the .JS

```
function ValidateInput() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

if (name != '' && email != '') {
if (email.match(emailReg)) 
alert("Not a real Email address!");
return false;
}
alert("Missing feilds!");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Your `if` wouldn't be working.  Alert has no issues.

Comment: pull up the debug console (F12 in most browsers) to see if there are any error messages.  also check the network tab to make sure your script is loading.

Comment: Does your actual have a typo in the input too or is that just in the question here? `<input type="submit" value="Lets Go"`

Answer (score 0):

add a > to the end of this line:

```
<input type="submit" value="Lets Go"
```

For the validation, personally i would do it like this:

```
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
```

Comment: Yep.......I was missing the >. It alerts now if something is missing in one of the fields. It does not seem to be validating the email address however, I wonder if I have that set incorrectly.

Comment: Found it, needed to make it "if (!email.match"